# How to get all resource parameters details in Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Dears,

I'm wondering how to get all parameters of a specific resource, the "Get" command doesn't fetch all details !

Example, I need to get the IP of this Public IP Address

```
Get-AzResource -Name "PubIP"

Name              : PubIP
ResourceGroupName : RG1
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses
Location          : centralus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/xxxxxx/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PubIP
```

I've tried

```
Get-AzResource -Name "PubIP" | Where-Object { $_.Scope -contains 'address' }
```

But also didn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use the dedicated powershell cmdlet to fetch details of a resource.

For example, to get details of public ip address, you can use [Get-AzPublicIpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-3.5.0). The test result:

[image]